# $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(\alpha\cdot x)$

Tags: special-functions, recreational-mathematics, analyticity

I try to find an analytic increasing function $f_\alpha$ ($0\le\alpha\le1$) from $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^+$) to $\mathbb R$ such that for all $x$
$$f_\alpha(x+1)=f_\alpha(x)+f_\alpha(\alpha\cdot x)$$
and $f_\alpha(0)=1$. Hence $f(1)=2$.

Of course, there are some easy solutions $f_0(x)=x+1$ and $f_1(x)=2^x$, but how to find $f_{\frac{1}{2}}$ or any other $f_\alpha$ ? 
A way to find the sequence $\beta_n^{(\alpha)}$ such that $f_\alpha(x)=\sum_n\beta_n^{(\alpha)}x^n$ would be nice too.

Comment: Maybe try the guess f = e^{cx}?

Comment: what do you mean by $\alpha.x$ is it multiplication, i.e. $\alpha\cdot x$?

Comment: I think you can't find such a function in general but you must search of special forms of f you want, for example for $\alpha$=1 and searching between linear functions you get f=c(x+1).

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Yes it's multiplication.